# php $output .= include code from file

Tags: php, include, output

Just trying to tidy up a little bit of code here. I have a php command to output some html. However, one of my comands is quite a large amount of html, I was wondering if it's possible to output code referenced in a different file?

For example, my current php looks like this:

```
$output .= '<div class="contact-form '.$css_class.'" >';
$output .= '<h4 class="form-title">'.$title.'</h4>';                    
$output .= 'SOME VERY LONG CODE'
```

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
$output .= include('file_with_long_code.html');
```

instead? I aven't tested this, but am curious to know if it works or what the proper way of doing it is

Comment: Have a look at http://no1.php.net/file_get_contents

Comment: why not use NOWDOC/HEREDOC?

Comment: `$output .= file_get_content('file_with_long_code.html');`

Comment: file_get_contents won't parse his vars...

Comment: @DarkBee - An html file shouldn't have any vars that need parsing

Comment: Either you include the whole "command" from the file, and let it be processed, or you could include the content of that file without being processed.
Or you want to replace the $variables with their corredponding values, without needing to write "$output.=" ? or what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can instead use getfilecontent function of php

```
 $output .=  file_get_contents('file_with_long_code.html');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
    ob_start();
       include('somefile.php');
    $output = ob_get_contents();
```

Read more about output buffering in the docs: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

I recommend using a PHP Framework, most of them have a very good functionality for these Kinds of "Problems".

Answer (score 0):

html file.tpl.php:

```
<div class="contact-form <?=$css_class; ?>" >
<h4 class="form-title"><?=$title; ?></h4>
SOME VERY LONG CODE
```

main file:

```
<?php

ob_start();
include('file.tpl.php');
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

$output .= file_get_contents('file_with_long_code.html');

Yes, it is possible.